# using media query to remove indent on li

Tags: css, media-queries

I am using media queries to remove indent on li when the screen size is 500 width here the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row" style="margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 1px;">
            <div class="media">
                <div class="date pull-left">
                    <p>7<span>June</span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <p><strong>xxx</strong> xxxx/p>
                    <p>Key Points:</p>
                    <ol>
                        <li>xxx</li>
                        <li>xxx</li>
                        <li>xxxx.</li>
                        <li>sda</li>
                        <li>dasdaS</li>
                        <li>ASdaSDa</li>
                        <li>aSDas.</li>
                    </ol>
                    <a href="xxx"><img src="/static/images/YouTube-icon-full_color.gif"></a>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the corresponding css:

```
@media (min-width: 600px){
 ul{
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
   }
 li{
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
   }
}
```

Link to JS bin paste 
http://jsbin.com/xoqufugo/9/

My issue is its not working.

Comment: Are you trying to override inline styles with media queries? Stop doing that and everything will work

Comment: you are applying css to `ul` and you are using `ol` in HTML

Comment: Changed it.. no difference. http://jsbin.com/xoqufugo/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do below changes. Here is the [demo](http://jsbin.com/xoqufugo/11/edit)

change `min-width: 600px` to `max-width: 600px`

`0l` to `ol`